# Python Tkinter Object Oriented Coding Issue

Tags: python-2.7, text, tkinter

First off, I am exceedingly new to the whole Object Oriented structure. But basically, I've been fiddling around with Tkinter and I can't seem figure out this bug.

Basically, I'm trying to make some GUI with various parts, like a sidebar and a main board. So I wanted to divide the sidebar and the main board into two separate classes. But for some reason, it just isn't working.

```
class SideBar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        sidebarframe = tk.Frame(root)
        sometext = tk.Text(sidebarframe,...)
        button= tk.Button(sidebarframe, ... , command = self.do_something)

        sidebarframe.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        sometext.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        button.grid(row = 0, column = 2)


    def do_something(self):
        self.sometext.delete(1.0, END)
        ...

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.SideBar = SideBar(self)

        self.SideBar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

So basically, I want it so that when you press the button, it wipes the text clean and then prints out something new, but whenever I run it, it states that Sidebar instance has no attribute of "sometext".

I feel like I'm going crazy over this. I know I'm missing something...but I have no idea what.

Also, as I am a complete newbie to Object Oriented Structure for Tkinter, could some kind soul link me to some sample code, so I could study it? I've had enough tutorials, but have a lack of sample code. Thank you so much.

Comment: are the side bar and main board on the same page

Comment: By same page, do you mean the same window? Yes, I plan on them being  so.

Comment: I would have one class per window so your side bar and main board would be in same class. Then if you have distinct sections of GUI use frames. I will post an answer with some code later as currently in Manchester

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the unnecessary and seemingly confusing inheritance, and making sometext an instance object, this works as one would expect.  Note that object oriented programming rotates around an object that does one thing/solves one problem.  Inheritance does not equal object oriented.

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

class SideBar():
    def __init__(self, root):
        sidebarframe = tk.Frame(root)
        self.sometext = tk.Text(sidebarframe)
        button= tk.Button(sidebarframe, text="do something",
                          command = self.do_something)

        sidebarframe.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.sometext.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        button.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

        self.sometext.focus_set()

    def do_something(self):
        self.sometext.delete(1.0, "end")
        print "do something"

class MainApplication():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.SB = SideBar(self.parent)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh this looks much simpler and it works well. However, I had a follow up question. I understand that since the "sometext" Text Box is in the sidebarframe, you have to name it self.sometext, but suppose I had another frame called secondframe inside the sidebarframe and wanted to put a Text Box in there, how would I label that? self.secondframe.secondtext = tk.Text(...)?

Comment: self.sometext is an instance object of the SideBar class (whew).  The short version is that it can be seen and used anywhere in the SideBar class.  Try some test code with frame #2.  Since it is an instance object, it can also be accessed by using the instance in whatever object is aware of the instance, so in MainApplication, print self.SB.sometext.  It will print some kind of Tkinter ID, which would be the same ID as would be printed in SideBar.  Note that you could also delete the text from it from MainApplication but the purpose of a class is to handle all of that within the class itself.

Comment: So a second would be self.sometext_2 = tk.Text(sidebarframe_2).  The frame goes with the definition of the Text and has nothing to do with the variable that points to the object, i.e. self.sometext_2